# SignalR website returns a 404 when deployed on IIS

Tags: .net, iis-7.5, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am having an issue with the deployment of a SignalR 1.3.1 .NET 4.0 WebForms website in IIS. The site works fine from Visual Studio 2010 but returns a '404 - File or directory not found' when I use the deployed version. Behind the scenes the 404 comes when the client requests the ~/signalr/negotiate URL for negotiate.json file. Here is how my IIS looks:

[image]

Note that the bin folder here just has the .dll and .pdb for my SignalR 1.3.1 .NET 4.0 WebForms website. It doesn't have anything else.

Here is my Global.asax.cs code:

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Register the error handling pipeline module
        GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(new ErrorHandlingPipelineModule()); 

        // Register the default hubs route: ~/signalr/hubs
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration { EnableCrossDomain = true });
    }
```

Here is my SignalR Hub code:

```
public class EppafHub : Hub 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Sends notifications for new vehicle launches.
    /// </summary>
    public void SendVehicleUpdates()
    {
        try
        {
            Clients.All.SyncVehicleUpdates();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my WPF Client code:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;

// Establish a connection to the hub
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://MyServer:MyPort/");                
hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("EppafHub");

// Subscribe to the server events
hubProxy.On("SyncVehicleUpdates", new Action(() => SynchronizeVehicleUpdates()));

// Start the connection to the hub
hubConnection.Start().Wait();
```

I get the 404 error when I try to start the hubConnection. What am I doing wrong? Is there any way I can browse the hub from IIS to see if the issue is with the deployment or the code? I saw similar questions but none of the solutions work for me.

I have also installed various SignalR nuget packages directly on the IIS server as well.

And I have also cleared the Asp.NET cache using the following command:

```
net stop w3svc
Remove-Item -Path "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\*" -Force -Recurse
net start w3svc
```

Comment: Did you update the port number to what's in use on the server?  Are you using a port at all on the server?

Comment: @Erik I have specified a fixed port for the website.

Comment: did you open up incoming connections on the port? On Windows7 all incoming ports are locked down. I open the port I'm using with `> netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.1.42:58938/ user=everyone`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out, it was an OS issue. Everything works fine in Windows Server 2008 R2 and doesn't work in Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and adding the SignalR packages to the IIS machine resolved the problem (the IIS PC is different from my dev PC) .

1. Download the nuget.exe from http://nuget.org/nuget.exe.
2. Start a cmd shell (as Administrator) and navigate to your web directory. (Not sure this is required but it is part of what I did to get it working.)

   c:\inetpub\wwwroot>Nuget Install Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR

   c:\inetpub\wwwroot>Nuget Install Microsoft.Owin.Cors
3. in the cmd shell navaigate to

   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.3031
4. Run the aspnet_regiis command:

   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.3031>aspnet_regiis -i
5. Since I'm running a stand alone server and Windows7 has all incoming ports locked down by default I open the port using:

   > netsh http add urlacl url=http://1xx.168.1.42:58938/ user=everyone
6. I also packaged my SignalR client page by Publishing to Disk in VS 2013. The Web.config and packages.config files are probably what you are missing.

packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.6.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" version="2.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You might also try the more inclusive packages.config from the [MoveShape Demo](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-high-frequency-realtime-with-signalr) on the SignalR site.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.10.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" version="2.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="2.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" version="2.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" version="2.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Cors" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that your IIS server is configured with [the Extensionless URL handler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368/en-us).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Drew. But the update wasn't applicable for my server.

Comment: Ok, so it may be installed, but is the URL handler set up in IIS correctly? Also, can you update the question with the <system.web> and/or <system.webServer> section of your web.config?